# Modelado de tablas con esquema de MSSQL en ASP.NET CORE 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Estoy creando modelos en una aplicación MVC con ASP.NET Core 3.1, el problema es con las tablas que tienen esquema, hice un modelo con dbo y funciona normal, pero al momento de tomar una tabla con Esquema diferente a dbo la compilación dice que el nombre es inválido.

El modelo empieza así:

```
[Table("Esquema1.Tabla1")]
 public class Tabla1
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
```

Lo anterior me funcionaba en ASP.NET con Framework 4.7 pero en CORE 3.1 no.

Al compilar el error es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias

Comment: qué error te da exactamente?

Comment: SqlException: El nombre de objeto 'Esquema1.Tabla1' no es válido.

Comment: conoces entity framework y automapper? igual estas dos tecnologías te ayudan, pero el cambio es grande

Answer (score 0):

Después de investigar, supe que tuve un error al no llamar al esquema aparte, la solución fue:

```
[Table("Tabla1", Schema ="Esquema1")]
public class Tabla1
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
```